# Plotly: Changing the legend labels and aggregating numerical values

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

Here is my code:

```py
fig = px.bar(
    data_frame=dftotal, 
    x="YEAR", 
    y="OPINION",
    title="Score des opinions par années", 
    color="OPINION", 
    width=1300, 
    height=700, 
    template='plotly_dark',
    color_discrete_map={5: "green",4: "lightgreen",3: "yellow",2:"orange", 1: "red", "inconnu": "grey"}
)

fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

It gives this result:

[image]

But I would like to achieve, for each year, the result shown below on the year 2014. I think, by making a sum of the "total score" obtained by each value.

[image]

I would also like to change the labels name of the legend. Something like: "Very bad" instead of "OPINION=1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you did not provide sample data,  so I have simulated it
- **counts** you could use a histogram, I have chosen to use **pandas** `value_counts()` to generate a summary data frame for plotting
- map trace / legend names. Have used https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html to map from 1, 2, ... to "very bad", "bad", ...  NB use of `fillna()` for "inconnu"
- you could also choose to use `hover_data=["OPINION"]` if you want to see original value of *OPINION*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

dftotal = pd.DataFrame({"YEAR":np.random.choice(range(2010,2021),10000), "OPINION":np.random.choice(range(1,6), 10000)})
dftotal.loc[dftotal.sample(200).index, "OPINION"] = "inconnu"
dfp = dftotal.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={0:"COUNT"}).sort_values(["YEAR","OPINION"])

fig = px.bar(
    data_frame=dfp, 
    x="YEAR", 
    y="COUNT",
    title="Score des opinions par années", 
    color=dfp["OPINION"].map({1:"very bad",2:"bad", 3:"ok",4:"good",5:"very good"}).fillna("inconnu"),
    # width=1300, 
    height=700, 
    template='plotly_dark',
    color_discrete_map={"very good": "green","good": "lightgreen","ok": "yellow","bad":"orange", "very bad": "red", "inconnu": "grey"}
)

fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5)
```

[image]